# phpseclib OpenSSH or PuTTYgen key generation

Tags: php, rsa, sftp, phpseclib

I am trying to generate Private and Public RSA key, so I can pass it to supplier and connect to their SFTP server. 
I am using phpseclib for this, but whatever key I create, the supplier receive error message saying that the SSH key entered is invalid and not supported. Please enter a valid key (OpenSSH or PuTTYgen)

I have tried:

```
<?php
include('Crypt/RSA.php');

$rsa = new Crypt_RSA();

$rsa->setPrivateKeyFormat(CRYPT_RSA_PRIVATE_FORMAT_PUTTY);
$rsa->setPublicKeyFormat(CRYPT_RSA_PUBLIC_FORMAT_OPENSSH);

//define('CRYPT_RSA_EXPONENT', 65537);
//define('CRYPT_RSA_SMALLEST_PRIME', 982451653); // makes it so multi-prime RSA is used
extract($rsa->createKey()); // == $rsa->createKey(1024) where 1024 is the key size

echo $privatekey;
echo "\n\n\n";
echo $publickey;
?>
```

This is example of generated key:

```
PuTTY-User-Key-File-2: ssh-rsa
Encryption: none
Comment: phpseclib-generated-key
Public-Lines: 4
AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAAAgQDFkOp+otBkW4gkiNZ9xbWrWjzAok+iD+gc
GESAyE3FLMFteQtJbpHlsix2eeBTCTjgPXiaRHABtzeqyr6nuO44uXLotJ4WVHOJ
5G75QFWZL0j61LLWZmHB7oxF2Vdt7BFAINu/UbGAhBVRdBaNDRxKSW/10KToOC+b
1yhEAR9MXw==
Private-Lines: 8
AAAAgEZ1qXvieynfjw1glAalFWZ4N0SIXpgwzhn++adoSHwyuwVc7w6QVY4y3jKe
wsc6ecNXiQSTtdKW0k6iIh7VEHggCwMjVIi752jYhiV2wc2gSaP5PnjYyrRpsVb8
JjXZToYeRvWNvNPh4aS4x3CTSpB4BLcZ+7V451bNUy84XIM5AAAAQQDm+1RLu5o3
NmUazpJT3a/KpEtfO5Fg4RuBgFu0dXM6+lfueFUMxpVJ1JY1eWRtCD7gr0EqYC3U
HtNxuOoBk1pdAAAAQQDa9wkbrpQparL9GAoqWU4rP2bjBZ9Nd6fVozswgzGU4cUx
nuxvirPdQfwBAKk8czSH1bY64NVfNF8nhNXCTS3rAAAAQC3Sse80v03IRDg/gT29
VDeCj0P7chs7A0yQ3i4O/jf+s76hBGmpnif1bkkXENfue3Rswxsbq7CVy6Tww7W1
BFk=
Private-MAC: 89412f0a7977af0b8bd29bb67522628b4ab49ca8



ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAAAgQDFkOp+otBkW4gkiNZ9xbWrWjzAok+iD+gcGESAyE3FLMFteQtJbpHlsix2eeBTCTjgPXiaRHABtzeqyr6nuO44uXLotJ4WVHOJ5G75QFWZL0j61LLWZmHB7oxF2Vdt7BFAINu/UbGAhBVRdBaNDRxKSW/10KToOC+b1yhEAR9MXw== phpseclib-generated-key
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This really isn't as programming related question, but which part are you sending to them?

Comment: The public key as I will be connecting to their server. Should I send them the Private key instead?

Comment: No, the public key is correct, but it just wasn't stated.

Comment: I was able to log into an SSH server with your public / private key pair. My guess: your supplier doesn't know what they're doing. If they're using OpenSSH server the public key needs to be in the `/home/user/.ssh/authorized_keys` file.

Answer (score 0):

PuTTY keys have a `Private-MAC` section at the bottom that yours doesn't have. phpseclib generated PuTTY keys have this section in them. My code:

```
<?php
include('Crypt/RSA.php');

$rsa = new Crypt_RSA();
$rsa->setPrivateKeyFormat(CRYPT_RSA_PRIVATE_FORMAT_PUTTY);

extract($rsa->createKey());

echo $privatekey;
```

The output:

```
PuTTY-User-Key-File-2: ssh-rsa
Encryption: none
Comment: phpseclib-generated-key
Public-Lines: 4
AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAAAgQC61/qDBnv1Fhz7QUe5Bq9gBrUlS/sJZxiv
CR5/a1ZlaTbb+V9ayK/f/7YvF/m9OnLE8qVQPdrGQ511xdk9WSO5LABNLReOIT/t
ylbtM17Cl3If5BHm1jXK5Edxi5GPdOTfI3UJ2puoGsOxunKtDKflbbkIvPyoV/BJ
W5+bZE6Jgw==
Private-Lines: 8
AAAAgELxiS8SzqzkTGP1YrY3X/R+0r5XN82Jo71q/gNXOPBCv0YXVgPX7bPLEcJT
y8XxwBcyfOqADveEWFFPHuOtIW/lSui1WxXxxyhP3L+0Utt9SzhW8PKeciAAJjLg
EzvQT/njSsPL9dFkfci6Ayc6cilvodCWhuJO74b8FPpqHQ15AAAAQQDcsrV3p5Du
mFJ9fNvu3yer8poBaAU5QqsKgyMl7rnEnExEfIbo0utVUh2GYHeHRFJbTpErm8ia
+IgV3Mo50OCVAAAAQQDYuvoI7jbRltk/YvwjS1+nE+BaHlArnF5wQwZiKvxJxSzo
lF8nn+HTRBo9eGflCCBN5ZX4liq3VUFN1Eb/m0O3AAAAQQCNlBIwB1SorqE/7M8G
VfJaJZScayO8HUSFGDk6ufXV0HquvaRIUGKEuezoTZU/tru+Q9CRMomSH3gFLrUj
f7s8
Private-MAC: e00a2fc04cf1d1acfa0f148d606f0d590e90f844
```

That key opens just fine in puttygen.

My guess: you either did a bad copy / paste of the key, accidentally omitting a portion of the key, which'll hinder our ability to assist you, or...  you're using a modified version of phpseclib that removes the `Private-MAC` line.

I mean, I don't even think an excessively out of date version of phpseclib would explain the omission of that line as I think every version of phpseclib has included that line.

Comment: Hi,sorry I have skipped the Private-MAC in my post (now edited). However it's the public key that is getting rejected as I am only sending that one to supplier.

Comment: I'm now able to open your key in puttygen. I took your public key and put it in my authorized_keys file and was able to SSH into the machine with your private key just fine. You say "supplier receive error message". What is your supplier? If I'm able to login with PuTTY with the key you posted then it seems to me that your supplier is in error. PuTTY is the de-facto authority on the PuTTY format and if PuTTY likes the key and your supplier does not...  well your supplier is probably not as much an authority as PuTTY is. Or even OpenSSH since OpenSSH likes the public key as well..